# AWS LoadBalancer IAM Readonly Rule Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created custom IAM policy to have a read access to loadbalancer.  But I am getting error as...

> An error occurred fetching load balancer data: User:
>   arn:aws:iam::000000000000:user/xxxxxxxx is not authorized to
>   perform: elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers

Bellow is the policy.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        ],
    "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:000000000000:loadbalancer/*"
  }]
}
```

Please some one help with this.

---

Thanks

Sreekanth

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/799388/aws-loadbalancer-iam-readonly-rule-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I figured out. Bellow is the policies.

Read only AWS LB Access Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```